# Question on Lee's Chapter $14.6$ Exercise.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $\omega = x \, dy \wedge dz + y \, dz \wedge dx + z \, dx \wedge dy$ be a $2-$form on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I need to compute $\omega$ in Spherical coordinates. I have thus far

\begin{align}
\omega &= x \, dy \wedge dz + y \, dz \wedge dx + z \, dx \wedge dy\\
&=(\rho \sin \phi \cos \theta)\,d(\rho \sin \phi \sin \theta) \, \wedge \, d(\rho \cos \phi)\\
&+(\rho \sin \phi \sin \theta) \, d(\rho \cos \theta) \, \wedge d(\rho \sin \phi \cos \theta)\\
&+(\rho \cos \phi) \, d(\rho \sin \phi \cos \theta) \, \wedge \, d(\rho \sin \phi \sin \theta)  \\
&=(\rho \sin \phi \cos \theta)\, (\sin \phi \sin \theta\, d \rho \,+\rho \cos \phi \sin \theta \, d \phi +\rho \sin \phi \cos \theta d \theta) \, \wedge (\cos \phi \, d \rho - \rho \sin \phi \, d \phi)\\
&+(\rho \sin \phi \sin \theta) \,(\cos \phi \, d \rho - \rho \sin \phi \, d \phi) \, \wedge \, (\sin \phi \cos \theta \, d \rho+ \rho \cos \phi \cos \theta \, d \phi - \rho \sin \phi \sin \theta \, d \theta) \\
&+\rho \cos \phi (\sin \phi \cos \theta \, d \rho + \rho \cos \phi \cos \theta \, d \phi - \rho \sin \phi \sin \theta \, d \theta) \, \wedge (\cos \phi \, d \rho - \rho \sin \phi \, d \phi)
\end{align}

My question is, anywhere I see three variables, do I need to take the partial with respect to each variable individually ? In that case, this will get very messy.

EDIT: I took partials, did I do okay?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: YEEEEESH @EthakkaappamwithChai ok, down to business then!

Comment: I doubt someone will check through your partial derivative calculations... Anyway, an alternative is to rewrite the radial vector field $R=x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ y\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ in spherical coordinates first, and write the volume form $\mu=dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$ also in spherical coordinates (both of which are simple enough to do), and then take the interior product $\omega=R\,\lrcorner\, \mu$.

Comment: So you mean compute $R$ into $\mu$ after computing $R$ and $\mu$ @peek-a-boo

Comment: yes, so that way you do the whole calculation in spherical coordinates right from the beginning (of course this requires you to realize initially that $\omega=R\,\lrcorner\,\mu$)

Comment: @peek-a-boo So $R$ is the first component of $\mu$? And this gives us $\omega$?

Comment: So $\omega = R \lrcorner \mu$? @peek-a-boo

Comment: And by $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ you are referring to take the partial w.r.t. to $\rho \sin \phi \cos \theta$?

Comment: Oh I see why , is it because the $dx$ and partial w.r.t to $x$ cancel out leaving the wedge of $x \, dy \wedge  dz$?

Comment: proceeding in this way we get the remainder of $\omega$

Comment: @peek-a-boo is that correct

Comment: not really sure what you're saying. Just do the computation both ways, You'll know you have the right answer if both approaches give the same answer.

Comment: Will do! its a tough computation. By tough I mean lengthy. @peek-a-boo

Comment: @peek-a-boo if I have seen an intro to 3-manifolds using Schultens and intro to Riemann surfaces using Miranda, you think I could jump to chapter 14 of Lee and be good?